# SQL query to compare a sales rep metrics with a quartile average captured in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a sql query where it calculates my sales quartiles for past three months for all sales representatives and is captured in a temp table in stored procedure  like this:

### Quartile value of all sales representatives for past three months:

```
Date          25th%    50th%     75th%     100th%
 10/2020      88.89   90.00     95.00      100.00
 11/2020      85.63   91.00     96.00      100.00
 12/2020      70.00   80 .00    90.00      100.00
```

Now in my another CTE I have the actual values of the sales rep like this:

```
 SalesRepId     Month     salesvalue
  101           10/2020     77
  101           11/2020     90
  101           12/2020     100
```

When I do the join of both cte and temp table, the query performance is bad, what is the best way to look up the temp table for a sales value and assign the quartile to my salesrepid?

Basically for 10/2020 the salesvalue 77 is less than the 25th quartile then salesrep should get 25th quartile assigned for month of october.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my query so I can save the data into temp table instead of CTE. Now when I join the temp table , its a breeze.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/06/whats-better-ctes-or-temp-tables/

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `percentile_disc()` and `percentile_cont()`.  Unfortunately, these are not aggregation functions, but one method is:

```
select distinct month,
       percentile_disc(0.25) over (partition by month order by salesvalue) as value_25,
       percentile_disc(0.50) over (partition by month order by salesvalue) as value_50,
       percentile_disc(0.75) over (partition by month order by salesvalue) as value_75
from sales;
```

If you want to calculate the quartile, the simplest method is `ntile()`:

```
select s.*,
       ntile(4) over (partition by month order by sales)
from sales s;
```

You don't need to calculate the breaks.  The one caveat to `ntile()` is that the tiles are as close in size as possible.  That means that ties can be in different tiles.  To solve that, just do the calculation manually:

```
select s.*,
       ceiling(rank() over (partition by month order by sales) * 4.0 /
               count(*) over (partition by month)
              ) as quartile
```

Comment: I used these methods to bring the values for my quartiles, now i need to compare individual values with this quartiles value to decide which quartile they fall under

Comment: Currently i am joining both the tables on date and using a case statement to compare the value, but query is very slow when i do like that

Comment: @KarthikDooty . . . There are more direct methods to solve that problem.  I amended the answer.

Comment: Quartile is already calcuated and captured in a table variable. My problem is now comparing the value to the values in the quartile table, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Imagine you have two separate cte, one with quartile values, one with actual values, how do i compare the actual value with quartile value and get the quartile of the sale?